# How to calculate muscle and kg needed to obtain your body type you wanted

Tags: workout-routines, muscle, food, chest, biceps

i am 23 years old.I have a body like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG8G9.jpg .I am 1.81 inch,72 kg.I want to  obtain like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZDQ0.jpg.How much muscle kg should i add?How can i calculate it?

Comment: I don't know, but I can tell you it will take many years of consistency, so may as well start now. Also, did you mean 1.81 meters?

Comment: yes that i mean.I think its the same

Comment: I don’t even know how to begin to ask you to define what you mean by the picture’s body type. However, the first thing that comes to mind is the shoulder to hips ratio. This is a genetic thing. You should check out Virtuvian Physiques series on genetics as it relates to the body/aesthetics. —> https://youtu.be/xSe_tCO3VOI (That’s the final part, links to the other parts are in the description)

Comment: i didn't catch what you mean...Of course are genetics but i want to increase my body from one picture into the other.I mean to obtain(second picture ) that type of body.I want to calculate how much muscle or body fat needs more to be like this..If you check first picture and second.Thats it all.I tell my infos about me and i want to be like second picture.Genetics are different person to person.

Comment: There are so many little things that are different though. You’ll have to edit the question to include as many details as possible as to what specifically you want to obtain. If the answer is “everything” that’s fine too, but to save you the trouble, the answer to “everything” is “genetics”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this. I'll go from most basic to most complicated.

### Easy

The most barebones approach is find the weight of some people you want to look like, then translate your weight to that, accounting for body fat.

Let's say you are 72 kg at 10% body fat. Then let's say the body type you want to attain is 90 kg at 10% body fat.

- You have 65 kg of non-fat on you
- You need to get to 81 kg of non-fat for a comparable appearance

I say non-fat because there is more to lean mass than muscle. Water, organs, etc. More about this in a second.

Precise body fat can be very hard to come by, and you want to be careful about guessing too much. I'll have a link about that towards the end. In general though, if you can see a person's abs, they're likely 10%, or under.

### Fancier

An important caveat here is height. If you find someone who is a few inches shorter or taller than you, that throws the numbers off.

An old school way to approach this is for every inch above five feet, add five pounds.

So, all else being equal, a person who is 5'5" will weigh 25 pounds less than a person who is 5'10".

I honestly don't know where this number originally comes from. But there are a few numbers like this which float around in the exercise science world, and you'd be surprised how well they hold up.

(Another one is if you want to know your maintenance calorie intake, take your bodyweight and multiply by 15. e.g. most 200 lb people eat 3000 calories per day. Amazing how well that works. Not every time, but often enough.)

### The dedicated

Next, you can consider joint width. People with wider joints tend to have more muscle than those with smaller joints. There is a calculator for this, which I'll get to in a second.

### The hardcore

Finally, if you're going pretty out there on the muscle curve, and that aspirational picture suggests you are, you need to consider drug use.

Once you start getting around abs visible, 190+ plus pounds and average height, drug use becomes more and more likely.

I have no judgment against drug users, I'm merely saying it needs to be considered based on goals. The fact is drugs help hypertrophy. I find it worthwhile knowing, or at least having a very good sense, whether a goal can be attained without them or not. The earlier one has this knowledge, the better. For instance, if one isn't willing to take drugs, there is no point in chasing a Ronnie Coleman physique.

### More Help

If you're looking to get fancier:

Lyle McDonald has a good source for,

- [What’s My Genetic Muscular Potential?](https://bodyrecomposition.com/muscle-gain/whats-my-genetic-muscular-potential.html/)

Casey Butt has in my mind the best overall material on this-

- [Maximum Muscular Bodyweight and Measurements Calculator](http://www.weightrainer.net/bodypred.html)

I've personally used these approaches to see,

- [How many players in the NFL are on drugs?](https://b-reddy.org/how-many-players-in-the-nfl-are-on-drugs/) *<- This link has more info regarding issues with body fat measuring.*